# Automate excel file in Power BI when refreshes the report

Tags: powerbi, report, powerbi-desktop, powerapps

I need help in below PBI Requirement--

1. currently, we are using data from one static excel file in Power BI and whenever new changes are require, we edit the excel and save it into update file.
2. User's requirement is to have a form in power bi in which user can enter the data and it should get updated in the excel and loaded into the power BI.

Please let me know if any one have done this.

Manual I did but Dynamic it is not getting written some M-code and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your PowerBI dataset having excel data to power Apps(PowerApps visual),powerapps automatically creates a user editable form with available columns or you can create a form according to your requirement which you can access from power bi through powerapps visual.